# I want to get part of the class of a clicked element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

So, I have a function like this:

```
$('a.tdt-btn-*').click(function() {
            var class = $(this + "[class^=tdt-btn-*]"); // Need more here

            console.log(class);
        });
```

What I want to do is get the value of the wildcard part at the end. How could I do this?

Comment: `class` is supposed to be a string, right?

Comment: Yes, I just want to get the wildcard * at the end of the class and output as a string

Comment: With all chance, it would be better to rely on `data-*` attributes instead of just guessing on the class ending.

Comment: as moonwave99 is saying, it is not a best-practice to get a part of the class-string, instead using the data-* attributes makes your code a lot better and easier to work with, not just for yourself, but also for other potentional developers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('a[class*=tdt-btn-]').click(function() {
    var elClasses = this.className.split(/\s+/),
        elClassWildcard;
    for (var i = 0, len = elClasses.length; i < len; i++){
        if (elClasses[i].indexOf('tdt-btn-') === 0) {
            elClassWildcard = elClasses[i].replace('tdt-btn-', '');
        }
    }
    console.log(elClassWildcard);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6S5Qz/1/).

Incidentally, `class` is a reserved word in JavaScript and should, or *can*, not be used as a variable name (I believe an error is thrown if you do so).

References:

- [Attribute contains (`attribute*=value`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).
- [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 1):

#### Only one class:

Try this (`class` is a reserved word, so I'm using `clazz`):

```
 $('a[class^="tdt-btn-"]').click(function() {
        var clazz = $(this).attr('class').replace('tdt-btn-','')
        console.log(clazz);
 });
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CzK3B/)

#### Multiple CSS classes:

It will take the first occurrence of the `tdt-btn-*`.

```
$('a[class*="tdt-btn-"]').click(function() {
    var clazz = $(this).attr('class').match(/(tdt-btn-)(.+?)(?=(\s|$))/)[2];
    console.log(clazz);
});
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vdAJ/1/)

Comment: What if the element has more classes, like `tdt-btn-something someOtherClass`?